# can't pass props to material ui makeStyles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a form component with an input.

```
const CustomInput = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles(props);
  return (
    <FormControl className={classes.form}>
      <Input
        classes={{ input: classes.input, underline: classes.underline }}
      />
    </FormControl>
  );
};
```

In the useStyles I want to control the color of input underline (borderColor property) by setting it from the props:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  underline: (props) => ({
    '&:hover:not($disabled):before,&:before': {
      borderColor: '#D2D2D2 !important',
      borderWidth: '1px !important'
    },
    '&:after': {
      borderColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
      borderColor: props.borderColor
    }
  })
}));
```

However, when I do pass the property in another component `App.js` (shown below), it seems to be undefined and the color doesn't change. What am I missing here?
I have looked through similar questions here but still can't get it.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  underline: {
    borderColor: theme.palette.secondary.main
  }
}));

const App = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
return  <CustomInput
              labelText="Custom Input"
              className={`${classes.underline}`}
              inputStyles
            />
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be mixing `className` with passing props to `useStyles`. What you could do in the `App` component is passing a `borderColor` prop to `CustomInput`:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <CustomInput labelText="Custom Input" borderColor="green" inputStyles />
  );
};
```

If you want to override the child component's style with `className`, you have to pass the className as a prop and in the child component, add to its element's className:

```
const CustomInput = ({ className, borderColor }) => {
  const classes = useStyles({ borderColor });
  return (
    <FormControl className={`${classes.form} ${className}`}> // <--
      <Input classes={{ input: classes.input, underline: classes.underline }} />
    </FormControl>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit cant-pass-props-to-material-ui-makestyles]

As a side note, you can access to the theme by using a function signature for `makeStyles` or check out Material UI `useTheme` hook. [Docs](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#usetheme-theme)

Comment: Hi! But what if I need to pass the color from the theme? How can I access it?

Comment: In your code, aren't you already using the theme in `makeStyles`? (`borderColor: theme.palette.secondary.main`) Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Probably, you did. The `useStyles` where I define the `borderColor` is in the App component. I access the `theme` there and want to pass its value to the `CustomInput` component.I'm confused what's the best way to do it..

Comment: In your question, you have two `useStyles`. Is the first one the `useStyles` used in `CustomInput`?

Comment: And in the first `useStyles`, there is `borderColor: theme.palette.secondary.main`. If you didn't add `borderColor: props.borderColor` after it and override it, you would be using theme.

Comment: I think we're talking about different things again :D. the  fist `useStyles` where I specify `borderColor: props.borderColor` is used in the `CustomInput` component. the second `useStyles` where I say `borderColor: theme.palette.secondary.main` is used in the `App` component where I import `CustomInput` and want to pass it the `borderColor` value. hope, it's consice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216008/discussion-between-hangindev-and-iuliia).